# SKSpriteNode hidden under a UI Background Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, skspritenode

I have an `SKSpriteNode` that functions properly. But when I add a `UIImage`, the `SKSpriteNode` becomes hidden behind the `UIImage`. I have been trying to figure out why, but I am having a little bit of trouble and can't seem to figure out what I am missing to allow the `SKSSpriteNode` to appear on top of the UI background Image, instead of behind it where it can't be seen. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

```
import SpriteKit
import SceneKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


var blueBall:SKSpriteNode!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -5.0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    blueBall = SKSpriteNode( imageNamed: "ball")
    blueBall.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    blueBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: blueBall.size.width / 1.5 )

    blueBall.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    blueBall.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

    self.addChild(blueBall)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch> , withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.blueBall.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(35, 0)
    self.blueBall.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(4, 10))
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For draw order use the `zPosition` property:

> In your case you will need to give the **Sprite** you want to be displayed in front a higher `.zPosition` value than the one to be displayed further back.

*Example: `ball.zPosition = 10`*

---

`zPosition` *definition*:

The height of the node relative to its parent.

**Tipps:**
The default value is 0.0. The positive z axis is projected toward the viewer so that nodes with larger z values are closer to the viewer.

Comment: The background image should be a position default of 0.0 correct? I tried setting the blueballl.zPosition = 15 but the ball still appears behind the UI back ground image.

Comment: Update: I got it to work! Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: Would you mind marking the answer as solved? @Seed12

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: do you see the 0 with an arrow up and down on the left of my answer. right next to it you should see a checkmark. Just check it and you are good. btw the arrows are used to vote on a question. => arrow up = good answer/question @Seed12

Comment: Thank you! I would up vote the answer but I need a reputation of at least 15.